# MS Office openxml get slide layout of powerpoint slide

Tags: powerpoint, openxml

I'm extracting data from powerpoint documents by reading the underlying xml.

**I want to get the name of the slide master layout that a particular slide is using, but I can't figure out how to get this info from the slide element in question.**

For example,  My slide master has many layouts, and one is called `1_Title Slide`.

I can open the xml and find the list of slide master layouts and names pretty easily.  The slidemaster layout that I want looks like this:

`<p:sldLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main" showMasterSp="0" userDrawn="1"><p:cSld name="1_Title Slide"> ... </p:sldLayout>`

Where the layut name is clearly `1_Title Slide`.

However, when I search for that string within the `<p:sld />` slide element that I know is using that layout, I cannot find that text.  The layout has a lot of different elements and attributes, presumably because the layout in question has several placeholders and shapes, and so it's not easy to find out how the xml may be referencing it.  What tag or attribute in openxml stores the "unique id" of the layout within the slide element?  How is it mapped?

Comment: I wonder if python-pptx can do this for you - or at least inspire you as to how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know, a layout with a title like 1_Title Slide is an accidental layout that got there by pasting in a slide from a different presentation. It's not native to the template or theme.

For references to relationships among XML parts, look in the **_rels** folder for the relationship file. So *slide1.xml* will have a file in there called **slide1.xml.rels**. One of the entries will look something like this:

```
<Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/slideLayout" Target="../slideLayouts/slideLayout7.xml"/>
```

Then open slideLayout7.xml and get the layout name.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk), Open XML SDK is defined this way:

> The Open XML SDK 2.5 simplifies the task of manipulating Open XML packages and the underlying Open XML schema elements within a package. The Open XML SDK 2.5 encapsulates many common tasks that developers perform on Open XML packages, so that you can perform complex operations with just a few lines of code.

But it looks like solving your problem with slide layouts with the Open XML SDK is not easy. If you use [Aspose.Slides for .NET](https://products.aspose.com/slides/net/) you will get the slide layout as shown below:

```cs
using var presentation = new Presentation("example.pptx");
var firstSlide = presentation.Slides[0];
var layoutName = firstSlide.LayoutSlide.Name;
```

[Documentation](https://docs.aspose.com/slides/net/) | [API Reference](https://apireference.aspose.com/slides) | [Free forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/slides/)

You can also evaluate [Aspose.Slides Cloud](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/) for presentation manipulating. This REST-based API allows you to make 150 free API calls per month for API learning and presentation processing.

I work at Aspose.

Comment: This line: "using var presentation = new Presentation("example.pptx")" leads me to think that your example is automating an instance of PowerPoint. Is that correct?  If so, note that OP may be working with the XML because they can't assume that PPT is installed.

Comment: Aspose.Slides for .NET does not require PowerPoint installation. This line of code creates an instance of the Presentation class. API Reference: https://apireference.aspose.com/slides/net/aspose.slides/presentation

Comment: Thanks for the correction. That's very good to know.